# TreeView IsSelected property returns the ItemsSource collection as 'This' pointer

Tags: wpf, xaml, treeview, wpf-controls

I have a TreeView which binds to a datasource like this

```
 <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Data}" Width="190"  >
```

JinkData is defined in my ViewModel as a property of a class. The property is defined like this

```
public Collection<JinkData> Data { get; set; }
```

I have a property IsSelected which tells me which node of the TreeView is currently selected and then I can use the 'this' pointer to get the selected node using the following code.

```
     private static object _selectedItem = null;
    // This is public get-only here but you could implement a public setter which also selects the item.
    // Also this should be moved to an instance property on a VM for the whole tree, otherwise there will be conflicts for more than one tree.
    public static object SelectedItem
    {
        get { return _selectedItem; }
        private set
        {
            if (_selectedItem != value)
            {
                _selectedItem = value;
                OnSelectedItemChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    static virtual void onselecteditemchanged()
    {
        // raise event / do other things
    }

    private bool _isSelected;
    public bool IsSelected
    {
        get { return _isSelected; }
        set
        {
            if (_isSelected != value)
            {
                _isSelected = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("IsSelected");
                if (_isSelected)
                {
                    SelectedItem = this;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        var handler = this.PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
```

The problem that I am facing is 'this' pointer in Set of IsSelected is the collection JinkData but I wanted this pointer to be the selectedJinkData insead of the whole collection. How can I get the currently selected JinkData from the TreeView?

How will I do that?

Comment: why do you have that property as static? Isn't it just simpler to have it as a normal public property of type `JinkData` and have your TreeView just bind to it directly. If you need to action on changes, do so in the property setter of the VM or for custom UI actions use a behavior?

Comment: I did that. It only calls the Get property. Does not call the set property

Comment: well if it's a public property implemented right only addition I can think of is to make sure you set the `Mode=TwoWay` in the `IsSelected` Binding?

Comment: `<Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding DataContext.SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}" />`

This is how I have done it. It only class the get property